# Is it possible to use relative paths in targetEntity through annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I googled this information but I couln't get the answer. What I want to do is to set targetEntity with a relative path, is that possible?

Here is an example:

```
AppBundle
|
|-Entity
  |-User.php
  |-OAuth
    |-Client.php
    |-AccessToken.php
```

AccessToken.php

```
Class AccessToken
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
   */
  protected $client;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="..\User")
   */
  protected $user;
```

`targetEntity="Client"` works because it's in the same namespace but `targetEntity="..\User"` doesn't. I know `targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User"` works but I wanted to use relative paths.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

What you pass into `targetEntity` is a namespace, not a path. You can either pass class name only if both your entities are in the same namespace (option 1) or pass full namespace (option 2):

**option 1:**

`targetEntity="Client"`

**option 2:**

`targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User"`

Comment: Just adding that the FQCN must not have a leading slash. See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html